# Python - printing x number of items per line

Tags: python-3.x

Python newbie. I've searched all over for a solution and all I manage to do is fix one thing and break another.

I need to print out a list of odd numbers between 1 and 50 and print 10 numbers per line.  The numbers on each row should be right justified.

This is probably the closest I've gotten, but I can't get the string values to align to the right.

```
   def odd() :
       rows = []
       row = '\t'.join(map(str,(i for i in range (1, 50, 2))))
       rows.append('{}'.format(row))
       print('\n'.join(rows))

   odd()
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuNCm.jpg)

I also tried this option, but I can't figure out how to get 10 per row, nor can I get them to justify.

```
def odd():
lower_limit =1
upper_limit = 50


for i in range (lower_limit, upper_limit,2):
    print("{:>5}".format(i), end="")

print()

odd()
```

[Sample Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01uVy.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.  Please explain as simply as possible as I'm still learning.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First create a `list` of all the `numbers` which have been `right-justified` as `strings`, then `print` them:

```
def oddTable(width, lim):
    nums = [str(i).rjust(len(str(lim))+1) for i in range(1, lim, 2)]
    print('\n'.join(''.join(nums[i:i+width]) for i in range(0, len(nums), width)))
```

and some tests:

```
>>> oddTable(10, 50)
  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
 41 43 45 47 49
>>> oddTable(20, 200)
   1   3   5   7   9  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39
  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73  75  77  79
  81  83  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99 101 103 105 107 109 111 113 115 117 119
 121 123 125 127 129 131 133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149 151 153 155 157 159
 161 163 165 167 169 171 173 175 177 179 181 183 185 187 189 191 193 195 197 199
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the list of numbers as you have done then iterating over the list as many times as needed is the answer.

```
from math import ceil

def odd_numbers(upper_limit, chunk_size):
        lst = [i for i in range(1, upper_limit, 2)]
        size = len(lst)
        num_lines = ceil(size/chunk_size)
        for i in range(0, num_lines):
                print(" ".join([str(i) for i in lst[i*chunk_size+1 : (i+1)*10]]))

odd_numbers(50, 10)
```

The last two lines, the loop, of the function can be rewritten as list comprehension but IMO it will be hard to read that way.